# add values from dynamically added rows into database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

hi i am working on a php form which has to add a table row dynamically when add button is pressed and i am using for loop to save the values  the problem is that it is not saving the data into my database and gives the error that the loop values of my textbox is undefined 
can anyone help me
here is my script

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var i=1;
function addRow()
{
          var tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
          var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
          var iteration = lastRow - 1;
          var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

          var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
          var el = document.createElement('input');
          el.type = 'text';
          el.name = 'name' + i;
          el.id = 'name' + i;
          el.size = 20;
          el.maxlength = 20;
          firstCell.appendChild(el);

          var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
          var el2 = document.createElement('input');
          el2.type = 'text';
          el2.name = 'address' + i;
          el2.id = 'address' + i;
          el2.size = 20;
          el2.maxlength = 20;
          secondCell.appendChild(el2);

          var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2);
          var el3 = document.createElement('input');
          el3.type = 'text';
          el3.name = 'contactNum' + i;
          el3.id = 'contactNum' + i;
          el3.size = 20;
          el3.maxlength = 20;
          thirdCell.appendChild(el3);
          alert(i);
          i++;
          frm.h.value=i;
          alert(i);

}
</script>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title></head>

<body>
<form action="submit.php" method="post" name="frm" id="frm">
<table width="40%" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Address</strong> </td>
    <td><strong>Contact Num</strong> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="20" maxlength="20" /></td>
    <td><input name="address" type="text" id="address" size="20" maxlength="20" /></td>
    <td><input name="contactNum" type="text" id="contactNum" size="20" maxlength="12" /></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow();" />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<label>
<input name="h" type="hidden" id="h" value="0" />
</label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

hereis my submit.php code

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", '')or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
$num =  $_POST['h'];
for($i=0;$i<=$num;$i++)
{

        $name       = $_POST["name_$i"];
        $address    = $_POST["address_$i"];
        $contactNum = $_POST["contactNum_$i"];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `com`(`name`, `add`, contact) Values('$name', '$address', '$contactNum')") or die(mysql_error());
}
echo "<h1>Done!</h1>";

?>
```

Comment: You should stop using the php's old mysql extension. Use PDO or mysqli instead, your code is vulnerable to multiple security problems otherwise. Oh, and also don't use the root account inside that database or normal tasks. Especially not without a password...

Comment: i am  just a beginner so i just know mysql so can u please help me in solving my problem with mysql

Comment: Well, first you access the wrong POST variables. You script names your html input fields like 'name15', _whithout_ an `_`. Second, it usually is better to use an array notation for such variables. So something like `'address[' + i + ']'`. You can access the POST variables more easy then.

Comment: i accept and wht should i do to save the values into my database?

Comment: If you really don't want to switch to use PDO (you _really_ should) then at least use the `mysql_real_escape()` function. You code is wide open to 'sql injection' otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will solve your problem and insert data in database.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var i=1;
function addRow()
{
      var tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
      var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
      var iteration = lastRow - 1;
      var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

      var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
      var el = document.createElement('input');
      el.type = 'text';
      el.name = 'name_' + i;
      el.id = 'name_' + i;
      el.size = 20;
      el.maxlength = 20;
      firstCell.appendChild(el);

      var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
      var el2 = document.createElement('input');
      el2.type = 'text';
      el2.name = 'address_' + i;
      el2.id = 'address_' + i;
      el2.size = 20;
      el2.maxlength = 20;
      secondCell.appendChild(el2);

      var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2);
      var el3 = document.createElement('input');
      el3.type = 'text';
      el3.name = 'contactNum_' + i;
      el3.id = 'contactNum_' + i;
      el3.size = 20;
      el3.maxlength = 20;
      thirdCell.appendChild(el3);
     // alert(i);
      i++;
      frm.h.value=i;
    //  alert(i);
}
</script>
```

In make change in according to below :

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="name_0" type="text" id="name_0" size="20" maxlength="20" /></td>
    <td><input name="address_0" type="text" id="address_0" size="20" maxlength="20" /></td>
    <td><input name="contactNum_0" type="text" id="contactNum_0" size="20" maxlength="12" /></td>
</tr>
```

In submit.php made change like below.

```
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are incrementing "i" one too many times.

```
      i++;
      frm.h.value=i;
```

should be

```
      frm.h.value=i;
      i++
```

or you could adjust the for loop:

```
     for($i=0; $i < $num; $i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of the textbox is undefined - in PHP you are lookin for name_$i (with "_") and in javascript the names are without "_" (el.name = 'name' + i;)

Also pay attention that in your javascript your loop starting from 1 (- in your php). The first client side row is comming from HTML but there you didn't put any index (name="name" instead of name="name_0"). It's better even not to fill the table with any row and just call the function (with i=0) when the page is loaded.